# Use output of one AWS Cloudwatch query into another in log insights

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

I have a use case where I have logs as below:
LINE1 : {id : 123, name : "ABC"}
LINE2 : {id : 123, city : "NYC"}

I want to query the log group and join 2 log lines with id field and get Output as :
**{name : "ABC", city : "NYC"}**

Is there a way to do this in cloud watch log insights? This is like a join or using output of one query into another.

I have separate queries with me but I am not sure how to combine those into one:

Query 1:
filter @message like /name : / | parse 'id : [ * ], name : [ * ]' as id, name

Query 2:
filter @message like /city : / | parse 'id : [ * ], city : [ * ]' as id, city

Comment: have you seen this post, which I have used to do something similar - https://saturncloud.io/blog/how-to-combine-two-cloudwatch-insights-queries/#:~:text=Combining%20two%20Cloudwatch%20Insights%20queries,average%20on%20the%20combined%20data.